# ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobService' when using Azure Backend

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-blob-storage

I followed these instructions to set up Azure as my backend service:
http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/azure.html

Also added additional packages per this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage

Getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/azure_storage.py", line 23, in <module>
    from azure.storage.blob.blobservice import BlobService
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage.blob.blobservice'
```

....

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/azure_storage.py", line 26, in <module>
    from azure.storage import BlobService
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobService'
[12/Oct/2017 01:38:00] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 18034
```

My pip3 freeze looks like so:

```
(venv) Mikes-MacBook:drhazelapp mikebz$ pip3 freeze | grep azure
azure==2.0.0
azure-batch==3.0.0
azure-common==1.1.8
azure-datalake-store==0.0.17
azure-graphrbac==0.30.0
azure-keyvault==0.3.7
azure-mgmt==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-authorization==0.30.0
azure-mgmt-batch==4.0.0
azure-mgmt-cdn==0.30.3
azure-mgmt-cognitiveservices==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-compute==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry==0.2.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-analytics==0.1.6
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-store==0.1.6
azure-mgmt-devtestlabs==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-dns==1.0.1
azure-mgmt-documentdb==0.1.3
azure-mgmt-iothub==0.2.2
azure-mgmt-keyvault==0.31.0
azure-mgmt-logic==2.1.0
azure-mgmt-monitor==0.2.1
azure-mgmt-network==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-rdbms==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-redis==4.1.0
azure-mgmt-resource==1.1.0
azure-mgmt-scheduler==1.1.3
azure-mgmt-sql==0.5.3
azure-mgmt-storage==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-trafficmanager==0.30.0
azure-mgmt-web==0.32.0
azure-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-servicebus==0.21.1
azure-servicefabric==5.6.130
azure-servicemanagement-legacy==0.20.6
azure-storage==0.34.3
azure-storage-blob==0.37.0
azure-storage-common==0.37.0
azure-storage-file==0.37.0
azure-storage-nspkg==2.0.0
msrestazure==0.4.14
```

Comment: Did you fix this. i am facing this right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you `pip install azure`, you installed `azure-storage 0.34.3` (tutorial 1). When you followed the second tutorial, you installed `azure-storage-blob 0.37.0`. This is where you got issues, there is massive breaking changes in 0.37.0 in the namespaces:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/BreakingChanges.md#version-0370

See in the ChangeLog that `azure-storage` <= 0.36 is incompatible with `azure-storage-blob` >= 0.37. You silently replaced some code file of 0.34.3 by 0.37.0 version.

In you second test, you said you did:

```
pip3 install azure-storage-blob
pip3 install azure
```

Package are still incompatible, but you did it in a reverse order, where you crushed your 0.37.0 version with the 0.34.3 one this time. It's why it works.

TLDR, someone needs to update django-storages to support azure-storage-blob >= 0.37.0. In the mean time, stick to `azure-storage` <= 0.36 and DON'T install `azure-storage-blob` at all.

Comment: you are correct, things started breaking when I pushed the Docker container up and was no longer doing the installs manually.  I will try your method.

Comment: So just installing Django-storages and azure-storage=0.36 yield an error:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/storages/backends/azure_storage.py", line 26, in <module>
    from azure.storage import BlobService
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobService'.
I am uncertain whether to install more libraries and of what version to not accidentally get a library mixup.

Answer (score 16):

In newer versions of `azure-storage-blob` the import `BlockBlobService` has been renamed to `BlobServiceClient`.

Updating your import statement to below should resolve your issue:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
```

An example of this can seen in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#set-up-the-app-framework).

Comment: Could you tell for which version it got updated?

Comment: From Laurent's answer it looks like this change was introduced in version 0.37

Answer (score 4):

I had to downgrade to `azure-storage-0.20.0` which fixed the issue, the newer versions couldn't find the `BlobService` class.

Answer (score 1):

Before the merge the current azure storage library doesn't work.  So to get this to work I had to install a private fork of Django storages:

I forked: https://github.com/guydou/django-storages/tree/upgrade_azure
and pointed to my own repo:

```
pip3 install -e 'git+https://github.com/mikebz/django-storages.git#egg=upgrade_azure'
```

then install blob library and azure SDK:

```
pip3 install azure
pip3 install azure-storages==0.34.3
```

After that the configuration seemed to work.  The final requirements document from azure were this:
(venv) Mikes-MacBook:drhazelapp mikebz$ pip3 freeze

```
adal==0.4.7
appnope==0.1.0
asn1crypto==0.23.0
astroid==1.5.3
azure==2.0.0
azure-batch==3.0.0
azure-common==1.1.8
azure-datalake-store==0.0.17
azure-graphrbac==0.30.0
azure-keyvault==0.3.7
azure-mgmt==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-authorization==0.30.0
azure-mgmt-batch==4.0.0
azure-mgmt-cdn==0.30.3
azure-mgmt-cognitiveservices==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-compute==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry==0.2.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-analytics==0.1.6
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-store==0.1.6
azure-mgmt-devtestlabs==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-dns==1.0.1
azure-mgmt-documentdb==0.1.3
azure-mgmt-iothub==0.2.2
azure-mgmt-keyvault==0.31.0
azure-mgmt-logic==2.1.0
azure-mgmt-monitor==0.2.1
azure-mgmt-network==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-rdbms==0.1.0
azure-mgmt-redis==4.1.0
azure-mgmt-resource==1.1.0
azure-mgmt-scheduler==1.1.3
azure-mgmt-sql==0.5.3
azure-mgmt-storage==1.0.0
azure-mgmt-trafficmanager==0.30.0
azure-mgmt-web==0.32.0
azure-nspkg==2.0.0
azure-servicebus==0.21.1
azure-servicefabric==5.6.130
azure-servicemanagement-legacy==0.20.6
azure-storage==0.34.3
certifi==2017.7.27.1
cffi==1.11.2
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.1.1
decorator==4.1.2
Django==1.11.5
django-extensions==1.9.1
-e git+https://github.com/mikebz/django-storages.git@5d073159adc0138f5acef121c2d578f4eba96d7c#egg=django_storages
django-webpack-loader==0.5.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
ipython==6.2.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isodate==0.6.0
isort==4.2.15
jedi==0.11.0
keyring==10.4.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
msrest==0.4.17
msrestazure==0.4.15
oauthlib==2.0.4
olefile==0.44
parso==0.1.0
pep8==1.7.0
pexpect==4.2.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==4.3.0
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
ptyprocess==0.5.2
pycparser==2.18
Pygments==2.2.0
PyJWT==1.5.3
pylint==1.7.2
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.22
wcwidth==0.1.7
whitenoise==3.3.1
wrapt==1.10.11
```

Comment: ERROR: Requested django-storages from git+https://github.com/mikebz/django-storages.git#egg=upgrade_azure has different name in metadata: 'django-storages'

Answer (score 0):

Strange... In Azure official documentation, it says you need to `from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService`, but what you did is `from azure.storage.blob.blobservice import BlobService` and `from azure.storage import BlobService`.

So why don't you just follow the official documentation?

Comment: Azure Storage provided by django seems out-of-date.

Comment: I am actually not writing those imports.  I have a Django project where I am using Azure as a backend service.  The import is in the official library.  I think somehow people through versioning or sequencing imports get a work around.  Looking for that work around.

Comment: question - is the only way to use Azure Blog storage to hand craft your own implementation?

Comment: @mikebz See this pull request: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/pull/394, the answer is "Yes" at least now.

Comment: thank you!  Did it break with some version?  I am curious if I can pull in a different version that's compatible with Django 1.11 and Python 3.6 so I don't have to hand craft this stuff.  One of the reason to use the framework is to avoid handcrafting basic services...

Comment: @mikebz In its source code, it shows `django-storages` may only support `azure-storage 0.20.0` which is a very old version. I am not sure whether it can work or not now.

Comment: going to try it now and report back.