# Azure Storage Python SDK : Uploading file to Azure blob storage without writting it on my disk

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a lot of Images from my Apache server that I want to put to azure. 
I cannot afford to do it in a sequential manner , SO I will add threading afterwards. I can access those images from a given URL and build a list on that. Easy. 
Now I do not have enough disk space for downloading the image and uploading it then delete it. I would like something cleaner.

Now is there a method to do that ?

Something like :

```
block_blob_service.AZURECOMMAND(container, source_URL, target_blob_name)
```

If not possible, is there a workaround ?

here is the complete code I have today ( download and then upload which I want to avoid ): 
**EDIT : Thanks to Gaurav Mantri I got it now. I update the code.**

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from os.path  import basename
    import os
    import sys
    import urllib
    import urllib2
    import urlparse
    import argparse
    import json
    import config
    import random
    import base64
    import datetime
    import time
    import string
    from azure.storage import CloudStorageAccount, AccessPolicy
    from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PageBlobService, AppendBlobService
    from azure.storage.models import CorsRule, Logging, Metrics, RetentionPolicy, ResourceTypes, AccountPermissions
    from azure.storage.blob.models import BlobBlock, ContainerPermissions, ContentSettings
    #from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
    from azure.storage import *

    #from azure.storage.blob.blobservice import BlobService

    CURRENT_DIR = os.getcwd()
    STORING_DIRECTORY_NAME = "stroage_scrapped_images"
    STORING_DIRECTORY = CURRENT_DIR+"/"+STORING_DIRECTORY_NAME

    if not os.path.exists(STORING_DIRECTORY):
        os.makedirs(STORING_DIRECTORY)

    def randomword(length):
       letters = string.ascii_lowercase
       return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

    startdate = time.clock()

    metadata_loaded = {'Owner': 'ToBeAddedSoon', 'Date_Of_Upload': startdate, 'VAR_2': 'VAL_VAR_2','VAR_3': 'VAL_VAR_3','VAR_4': 'VAL_VAR_4'}

    with open("credentials.json", 'r') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        StoAcc_var_name = data["storagacc"]["Accountname"]
        StoAcc_var_key = data["storagacc"]["AccountKey"]
        StoAcc_var_container = data["storagacc"]["Container"]
        #print StoAcc_var_name, StoAcc_var_key, StoAcc_var_container


    def copy_azure_files(source_url,destination_object,destination_container):
            blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=StoAcc_var_name, account_key=StoAcc_var_key)
            blob_service.copy_blob(destination_container, destination_object, source_url)

    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=StoAcc_var_name, account_key=StoAcc_var_key)

    def upload_func(container,blobname,filename):
        start = time.clock()
        block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
            container,
            blobname,
            filename)
        elapsed = time.clock()
        elapsed = elapsed - start
        print "*** DEBUG ***  Time spent uploading API " , filename , " is : " , elapsed , " in Bucket/container : " , container

    #URL_TARGET = "https://mouradcloud.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/blog/blog/category/food/"
    URL_TARGET = "https://www.cdiscount.com/search/10/telephone.html"
    base_url = URL_TARGET
    out_folder = '/tmp'
    r = requests.get(URL_TARGET)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")


    for link in soup.find_all('img'):
            src = link
            image_url = link.get("src")
            while image_url is not None :
                    if 'http' in image_url:
                            blocks = []
                            if image_url.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
                                    print " ->>>>>>>>>>>>>> THIS IS AN IMAGE ... PROCESSING "
                                    file_name_downloaded = basename(image_url)
                                    file_name_path_local = STORING_DIRECTORY+"/"+file_name_downloaded
                                    with open(file_name_path_local, "wb") as f:
                                            f.write(requests.get(image_url).content)
                                    filename_in_clouddir="uploads"+"/"+file_name_downloaded
                                    #upload_func(StoAcc_var_container,filename_in_clouddir,file_name_path_local)
                                    copy_azure_files(image_url,filename_in_clouddir,StoAcc_var_container)


                                    break
                            else :
                                    print " ->>>>>>>>>>>>>> THIS NOT AN IMAGE ... SKIPPING "
                                    break
                    else :
                            print " ->>>>>>>>>>>>>> THIS IS A LOCAL IMAGE ... SKIPPING "
                            break
            continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there's something exactly like this: [`copy_blob`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py#L2935)

```
block_blob_service.copy_blob(container, target_blob_name, source_URL)
```

Please keep in mind that this copy operation is asynchronous server side copying, thus:

- Source of the copy should be publicly available.
- You must wait for the copy operation to finish before deleting source items.

**UPDATE**

Modified code (I have not tried running it)

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from os.path  import basename
    import os
    import sys
    import urllib
    import urllib2
    import urlparse
    import argparse
    import json
    import config
    import random
    import base64
    import datetime
    import time
    import string
    from azure.storage import CloudStorageAccount, AccessPolicy
    from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PageBlobService, AppendBlobService
    from azure.storage.models import CorsRule, Logging, Metrics, RetentionPolicy, ResourceTypes, AccountPermissions
    from azure.storage.blob.models import BlobBlock, ContainerPermissions, ContentSettings

    CURRENT_DIR = os.getcwd()
    STORING_DIRECTORY_NAME = "stroage_scrapped_images"
    STORING_DIRECTORY = CURRENT_DIR+"/"+STORING_DIRECTORY_NAME

    if not os.path.exists(STORING_DIRECTORY):
        os.makedirs(STORING_DIRECTORY)

    def randomword(length):
       letters = string.ascii_lowercase
       return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

    startdate = time.clock()

    metadata_loaded = {'Owner': 'ToBeAddedSoon', 'Date_Of_Upload': startdate, 'VAR_2': 'VAL_VAR_2','VAR_3': 'VAL_VAR_3','VAR_4': 'VAL_VAR_4'}

    with open("credentials.json", 'r') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        StoAcc_var_name = data["storagacc"]["Accountname"]
        StoAcc_var_key = data["storagacc"]["AccountKey"]
        StoAcc_var_container = data["storagacc"]["Container"]
        #print StoAcc_var_name, StoAcc_var_key, StoAcc_var_container
    block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=StoAcc_var_name, account_key=StoAcc_var_key)

    def upload_func(container,blobname,sourceurl):
        start = time.clock()
        block_blob_service.copy_blob(
            container,
            blobname,
            sourceurl)
        elapsed = time.clock()
        elapsed = elapsed - start
        print "*** DEBUG ***  Time spent uploading API " , filename , " is : " , elapsed , " in Bucket/container : " , container

    #URL_TARGET = "https://mouradcloud.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/blog/blog/category/food/"
    URL_TARGET = "https://www.cdiscount.com/search/10/telephone.html"
    base_url = URL_TARGET
    out_folder = '/tmp'
    r = requests.get(URL_TARGET)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

    for link in soup.find_all('img'):
            src = link
            image_url = link.get("src")
            while image_url is not None :
                    if 'http' in image_url:
                            blocks = []
                            if image_url.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')):
                                    print " ->>>>>>>>>>>>>> THIS IS AN IMAGE ... PROCESSING "
                                    file_name_downloaded = basename(image_url)
                                    filename_in_clouddir="uploads"+"/"+file_name_downloaded
                                    upload_func(StoAcc_var_container,filename_in_clouddir,image_url)


                                    break
                            else :
                                    print " ->>>>>>>>>>>>>> THIS NOT AN IMAGE ... SKIPPING "
                                    break
                    else :
                            print " ->>>>>>>>>>>>>> THIS IS A LOCAL IMAGE ... SKIPPING "
                            break
            continue
```

Comment: This is not working, the documentation says : "param str copy_source: A URL of up to 2 KB in length that specifies an Azure file or blob." So the source has to be on azure storage ( file or blob ) already which is not my case.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you're using. I believe the documentation is incorrect. Copy source can be any publicly accessible URL.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code. However the code I am interested in seeing is where you're calling the `copy_blob` method which is not there.

Comment: I was on the point of doing it but After seeing that it has to be on azure blob or file, I did not and waited for your advice.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I took your code and modified it to make use of copy_blob method. Please give it a try. I have not tried to run this code so it might give some error. But hopefully it should give you some ideas. HTH.

Comment: I have a new issue... "ImportError: cannot import name BlobService" . I tried this SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700157/importerror-cannot-import-name-blobservice-when-using-azure-backend but not working. it seems this is depreciated. I am using python 2.7

Comment: There have been some breaking changes in Azure Storage SDK for Python recently where they split the package into multiple packages. Please refer to the breaking changes here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/BreakingChanges.md. Also, I would recommend that you take a simple example to work with the SDK (like creating a blob container) before undertaking such a complicated task.

Comment: Ok, I got it now on the SDK .......... ( man , you will lose people ! S3 is much more resilient ! Anyways )