# How to determine Azure python sdk version?

Tags: python, azure, azure-notebooks

I'm using `notebooks.azure.com` to learn python. I'm trying to [manage Blobs with python sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python-legacy).

MUCH of the documentation I come across mentions `pip install azure-storage-blob` then using the `BlobServiceClient` (class?) to interact with Azure Storage.

UNFORTUNATELY, I get the error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient'` when trying to call `from azure.storage import BlobServiceClient`. This occurs after installing and upgrading `azure-storage` (v0.36.0) and `azure-blob-storage` (v12.3.0).

[Here is a public Notebook showing the issue](https://pythonsdkissue-seadude.notebooks.azure.com/j/notebooks/blobserviceclientissue.ipynb)

[image: Error in action]

Does this mean notebooks.azure.com is using the `python v2.1 SDK` (which appears to use [*`BlockBlobService`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python-legacy#learn-about-the-sample-code) instead of *`BlobServiceClient`*)

How do I check which version of the python SDK my Azure Notebook is running?

**EDIT 1:**

- No change after running `!pip install azureml-sdk\[notebooks,automl\] --upgrade`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you [try](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-environment)

```
pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk\[notebooks,automl\]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However no change. Please see OP `EDIT 1`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700157/importerror-cannot-import-name-blobservice-when-using-azure-backend/49487666

Comment: seems like the solution is to create new environment virtualenv --no-site-packages --p python3 myenv

Comment: I'm using notebooks.azure.com. If i'm not mistaken, creating a virtualenv doesn't really make sense/isn't possible here. I can't run an Azure Notebook in a given venv because its hosted by Microsoft. I have no perms on the server beyond `user`. I don't think I can use a venv within a notebook to manage packages.

Answer (score 0):

azure-storage is deprecated, don't use that.

Comment: Your answer will be more helpful if you add a link to the depreciation notice, some docs., or any other source you have found the info from or find relevant.