# django file upload is not working in azure blob with new version

Tags: django, azure, django-rest-framework, azure-blob-storage, django-storage

After updated the azure blob version, it won't install everything. It will install specific version of namespace in the blob. So i installed the following packages.

```
azure-common==1.1.25
azure-core==1.8.1
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-storage-blob==12.4.0
```

i'm not able to upload the blob. All the references in the SO and other platforms are for old versions. For new versions there is no reference. The error i'm getting is

```
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions, ContentSettings
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobPermissions' from 'azure.storage.blob'
```

if i manually went to the path and removed the **BlobPermissions** from import compilation is happening. But upload is not happening, upload time i'm getting this error

```
connection_string=self.connection_string)
endpoint_suffix=self.endpoint_suffix)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token_credential'
```

Can anyone help me with proper doc for django azure upload with new version. The references i got in SO is manual upload way.

Some reference i got in SO:

1. [Upload and Delete Azure Storage Blob using azure-storage-blob or azure-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900507/upload-and-delete-azure-storage-blob-using-azure-storage-blob-or-azure-storage/58900508#58900508)
2. [ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobService' when using Azure Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700157/importerror-cannot-import-name-blobservice-when-using-azure-backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobPermissions' from 'azure.storage.blob'

`BlobPermissions` is used for the older version. It has replaced with [`BlobSasPermissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobsaspermissions?view=azure-python) for the new version.

---

It seems that `django.core.files.storage` is not supported by the [latest version(3.1)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/_modules/). So you could use the older version(e.g. 2.1) to upload file using django, or just use [azure-sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob).

With older version:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

f = open('file.csv', 'rb')
default_storage.save(path, f)
```

With Azure SDK:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="<connection_string>", container_name="my_container", blob_name="my_blob")

with open("file.csv", "rb") as data:
    blob.upload_blob(data)
```

Comment: yeah that's true. I can't use SDK. so i just downgraded the django-storage version for temporary.